# Android SMS not displayed even after inserting into database correctly

Tags: android, sms, restore

I am developing an SMS backup and restore app. I am able to backup the SMSs into a CSV file. However, when I try to restore the SMSs, the SMSs are stored perfectly into the SMS database. But they are not visible into the Messaging App in Android.

I am using the Content Provider for backup and restoring the SMSs. Following is the code I am using for Restoring the SMSs.

```
       CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
       Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
       String[] nextLine;
       while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put("_id", nextLine[0]);
            cv.put("thread_id", nextLine[1]);
            cv.put("address", nextLine[2]);
            cv.put("person", nextLine[3]);
            cv.put("date", nextLine[4]);
            cv.put("protocol", nextLine[5]);
            cv.put("read", nextLine[6]);
            cv.put("status", nextLine[7]);
            cv.put("type", nextLine[8]);
            cv.put("reply_path_present", nextLine[9]);
            cv.put("subject", nextLine[10]);
            cv.put("body", nextLine[11]);
            cv.put("service_center", nextLine[12]);
            cv.put("locked", nextLine[13]);
            this.getContentResolver().insert(uri, cv);
        }
```

Please Let me know, what mistake I am doing. I am trying to work things out for past 1 week, still I don't know my Mistake in the Code. What am I missing in the code?

Comment: did you checked the return value of `this.getContentResolver().insert(uri, cv);` ?

Comment: Yes. I checked the return value. It returns "content://sms/1", "content://sms/2". etc.. Is it correct?

Comment: Please Help. I tried lots of things, but I am unable to find a single solution to my problem.

Comment: yes, it seems correct

Comment: I am using Android 4.0 for the deployment. Does Android 4.0 and above supports SMS provider? Because, the native API documentation doesn't include SMS Provider.

Comment: Even if I change the Android Version to lower versions like 3.0, 2.2 even 2.1, Still the messages are not displayed into the Native SMS app. Please help somebody. Please.

Answer (score 1):

Do not include `_id` and `thread_id` in your inserts. After all records are inserted, do the following to trigger the conversations table threads update:

```
getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/conversations/-1", null, null);
```